# How to query the active record filtering by date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-console

How can I select **ALL** student students from my database with active status only in the month of May? I couldn't find it in the active record documentation. I only managed to query the students who were created in May, and not **ALL** students actived....

```
Student.where(status:'active', created_at: ('2021-05-01'..'2021-05-31')).count
```

**actually, my idea would go something like this:**

```
Student.where(status:'active', datetime: (('2021-05-01'..'2021-05-31')).count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the Date like so:

```rb
Student.where(status:'active', created_at: (Date.parse('2021-05-01')..Date.parse('2021-05-31'))).count
```

You could also let Rails set the beginning and end of the month:

```rb
Student.where(status:'active', created_at: (Time.new(2021, 5).beginning_of_month..Time.new(2021, 5).end_of_month))).count
```

If status ist an [enum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.6/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) you can also query like this:

```rb
Student.active.where(created_at: (Time.new(2021, 5).beginning_of_month..Time.new(2021, 5).end_of_month))).count
```

Comment: Also in Rails you could use `all_month` method (ex.: `Time.new(2021, 5).all_month`) https://apidock.com/rails/Time/all_month

Comment: I didn't know about `all_month`. Very cool! Thanks